# Protecting metal shed from rain

Tags: roof, metal, storage

My parents brought a large (6*40)metal storage container many years ago. They live in warm weather ( San Diego) but it does rain on occasion on the container leaked. My dad and brother tried numerous times to pack the leaks but without much success and it has laid unused for years. Being that they have no plans to get rid of it, I want to make it usable and was think of adding some sort of auxillary metal roof with a pitch that would divert most of the water. Any suggestions of the best way to go about this ( or an alternative solution) would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Is that 6 feet by 40 feet?  What is on the top of it now?

Comment: It's just its original, now rusty top. It's metal but I don't think it was properly weatherized

Comment: Have you thought about priming and painting the top again and putting this on a slight tilt?

Comment: The last mill I worked at we had several 8' x 40' containers. We ordered a membrane (roofing material) that was 10' x 41' rolled the bottom edge at the overhang and screwed it into the sides and back on every other rib or bump. It worked really well no leaks and I think it had a 10 year guarantee. Wish I could remember more but it was a few years back and the mill burned down 2 years ago.

Comment: Try a call to a local truss company and see what they would charge for making you wood trusses.  Then plywood, shingles and some steel angle brackets to secure it.